# How to Close TCP socket abruptly and reconnecting

Tags: sockets, tcp, embedded-linux, shutdown

We use Linux 2.6.33 on device. A PC application will be used which connects to the device over TCP socket. There will be a maximum of 1 MB of data transferred upon request from application.

Consider If the application is connected and working fine and in between the IP address of the device gets changed (which is possible with a command). Now the connection is broken abruptly at the application but on device it doesn't. But user expects to reconnect to the device with new IP address. In some cases the "send()' was halfway and may not have sent all data. Then this closing does not happen immediately. And hence user will not be able to reconnect until the socket is closed on device.

I use "shutdown(sock, RDWR), close(sock)" sequence.
The netstat output shows:

```
$ netstat -nt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0  29200 xx.xx.xx.xx:3000       xx.xx.xx.xx:50639       ESTABLISHED
```

As it shows the Send-Q is still not empty and so the connection is still in ESTABLISED state. This socket is closed after some time and I am not sure how much time it is. May be defined by socket implementation.

How can i close this socket immediately so that a new connection over same TCP port is possible from PC application?

Comment: It is defined by the time it takes to either complete the pending sends or abort them if they aren't being acknowledged. I don't understand the part about 'user expects to reconnect to the device with new IP address'. Why a new IP address?

Comment: Because the ethernet IP address is changed by a user command. Now the user needs to relaunch application again with the new IP address immediately after IP is changed by him.

Comment: How to find out the time it takes to close this orphaned socket by discarding the pending Send-Q packets ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'Ethernet IP address'. Which is it? The Ethernet address is changed? The IP address is changed? Both?

Answer (score 0):

It always take time to close a socket.But you can use `setsockopt()` to reuse the same port.Find more
  [detail](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#bind) on this link.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i close this socket immediately so that a new connection over
>   same TCP port is possible from PC application?

You can close it by calling close() of course, but what you really want to know is how to *detect* this condition so that you know when to call close().  The answer to that is:  not easily -- as far as your Linux device is concerned, the client at (the_old_ip_address) has simply stopped responding.  The Linux device has no way of knowing that this condition is due to the client's IP address having changed, rather than (say) a temporary network outage, so the Linux device will keep trying for a few minutes before it times out.

As far as resolving the problem you are having, probably the best way is to design your server so that it can accept and service multiple TCP connections at once.  If you do that, then it won't really matter if the old TCP connection sticks around for a few minutes, because the user will still be able to reconnect immediately from his new IP address and resume his work without having to wait.

That said, the other approach would be to add timeouts to your server such that if no data is sent or received on the TCP socket for N seconds (for whatever value of N you think is appropriate), the server then explicitly calls close() on the socket and listens for a new incoming connection.  This isn't a very good solution, though, since it makes an assumption about the performance of the TCP connection (i.e. that when in its "working" state its will always be sending or receiving data at least once every N seconds), and that assumption might not be true -- i.e. if your client and server don't want to send anything for a while, or if the network connectivity is bad enough that no data gets through for more than N seconds.  The risk is that this will lead to a false-positive, causing your server to close a TCP connection that was still valid.  Therefore I recommend the first approach rather than this one, if possible.